# Backbone add event firing double-triple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

Every time I add an item to my view, my add event is fired twice, then thrice for the second item added and so on and so forth. I am not sure if this has something to do with zombie views. If yes, am really confused as to where to call the close/remove function. I am creating a new firebase url collection for each `model_data` value. When the `model_data` value changes, the respective data must be displayed, apart from the ability to add and delete the items.

My code is as follows:

```
/*global Backbone */
var app = app || {};

(function($) {


    app.AppView = Backbone.View.extend({

        el: '#healthtracker',
        template: _.template($('#total-calorie-template').html()),

        initialize: function() {
            console.log("inside initialize");

            var self = this;

            this.model_date;
            this.input = this.$('#user-input');
            this.servings = $("#servings");
            this.total_calories = 0;
            this.records;
            this.list = $("#foodRecords");
            this.model_date = $('#date').val();
            this.dateUrl = "https://xxxxxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com/" + this.model_date;
            app.foodCollection = new app.FoodCollection([], { url: this.dateUrl });
            this.listenTo(app.foodCollection, 'add', this.addOne);

        },

        events: {

            'click #add-food': 'renderFood',
            'keyup #user-input': 'autoSearch',
            'change #date': 'newList'

        },


        autoSearch: function() {
            console.log("inside autosearch");
            $("#user-input").autocomplete({
                delay: 100,
                source: function(request, response) {

                    // Suggest URL
                    var suggestURL = "https://api.nutritionix.com/v1_1/search/%QUERY?results=0:10&fields=item_name,brand_name,item_id,nf_calories&appId=41324021&appKey=b16be109bec67fb1282c4b4559e8666f";
                    suggestURL = suggestURL.replace('%QUERY', request.term);

                    // JSONP Request
                    $.ajax({
                        method: 'GET',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        url: suggestURL,
                        data: JSON.stringify({
                            item_name: "",
                            brand_name: "",
                            item_id: "",
                            calories: ""

                        }),
                        success: function(data) {

                            if (data.hits.length != 0) {
                                for (i = 0; i < data.hits.length; i++) {
                                    response($.map(data.hits, function(item) {

                                        return {
                                            value: item.fields.item_name,
                                            item_name: item.fields.item_name,
                                            item_id: item.fields.item_id,
                                            brand_name: item.fields.brand_name,
                                            calories: item.fields.nf_calories

                                        }
                                    }));

                                }
                            } else {
                                response([]);
                            }


                        },
                        error: function() {
                            alert("Oops, something went wrong!");
                        },

                    })

                },
                select: function(event, ui) {

                    records = ui.item;
                }
            });
        },

        newList: function() {
            this.list.html("");
            console.log("inside newList");
            this.model_date = $('#date').val();
            this.dateUrl = "https://fiery-inferno-4707.firebaseio.com/" + this.model_date;
            app.foodCollection = new app.FoodCollection([], { url: this.dateUrl });

            //for each of those filtered items
            app.foodCollection.each(function(food) {
                var view = new app.FoodRecords({ model: food });
                this.list.append(view.render().el);
            });

            return this;

        },
        renderFood: function() {
            console.log("inside renderFood");
            app.foodCollection.create(this.newAttributes());
            this.input.val('');

        },

        addOne: function(food) {
            console.log("inside addOne");
            console.log(food);
            //$('#foodRecords').html('');
            var view = new app.FoodRecords({ model: food });
            this.list.append(view.render().el);


        },

        newAttributes: function() {
            console.log("inside newAttributes");
            return {
                item_name: records.item_name,
                brand_name: records.brand_name,
                calories: records.calories,
                item_id: records.item_id,
                servings: this.servings.val(),
                date: this.model_date

            }
        },

    });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Not sure directly from your code, but is it possible you're including your JS files multiple times?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I haven't included JS files multiple times.

Comment: So `addOne` is being called too many times? How often is `renderFood` called?

Comment: Renderfood is called only once when the add button is clicked.

Comment: There is something spooky about your code. Inside `newList()` you're creating an empty collection and then iterating over it creating views. How will that code ever run? Isn't `records` undefined inside `newAttributes`?  What is the content of `app.FoodRecords` ..? Try creating a [mcve] with minimal code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Records contains data from Nutritionix API, it is not undefined inside newAttributes. When I console.log app.foodCollection, I see all the data in there. I guess am doing something wrong with storing and retrieving data from Firebase API.

Comment: Where are you instantiating the view? can you update that in the question?This problem can happen when you try to re-render the view without unbinding the events associated with it.

Comment: You are instantiating the collection again and again on the click on add food button. That many listeners will be added. I think the collection should be instantiated only once and only a new model should be pushed each time add food button is clicked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Backbonejs event occurring multiple times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454388/backbonejs-event-occurring-multiple-times)